# Cannot Connect to the Internet After Installing Updates

Tags: windows-xp, auto-updates

I have Windows XP and yesterday all was fine. Installed auto updates before shutting down last night and now this morning cannot connect to the internet using either Firefox or IE.

Router is fine, wireless connection on this laptop I'm typing from, as well as my Blackberry.

I am not an IT guy by any means so wondered if anyone out there can help?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you can try, but since you've claimed you're not an "IT guy" I'll start with the easiest solution.

You can roll it back using System Restore, meaning your PC will (should) behave from before you did the update.

[This article on the Microsoft site explains it well](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084)

The main points are:

> Log on to Windows as an administrator.
>   Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Accessories, point to System Tools, and then click System Restore.
>       On the Welcome to System Restore page, click to select the Restore my computer to an earlier time option, and then click Next.
>       On the Select a Restore Point page, click the most recent system restore point in the On this list, click a restore point list, and  then click Next.
>       Note A System Restore message may appear that lists configuration changes that System Restore will make. Click OK.
>       On the Confirm Restore Point Selection page, click Next. System Restore restores the previous Windows XP configuration, and then restarts the computer.
>       Log on to the computer as an administrator. Then, click OK on the System Restore Restoration Complete page.

Of course, this will undo all the changes the updates made!

From memory, XP updates would revert some settings to 'default' and as such, the fault may be a simple change but hard to find if you don't know what you're looking for.

You may want to consider why you can't connect, you could roll back the network drivers from within Device Manager.

It could be a DNS issue and things are not resolving. If you know how, you can ping your router and see if there is a response and then try and ping an external source, such as 8.8.8. This will prove where the fault is. you can then review if you're using dynamic or static IP and if the details are correct.

Open Command Prompt and type `ipconfig /all` - if the whole page says multimedia disconnected (or similar) then the fault is the machine can't see the card and is more tricky.

**Edit**

Based upon your comments, please consider

Click on Start, click Run, type services.msc, and then press ENTER.
Search for the below mentioned Services. Right click it and select Properties or double-click it to open the service.
DHCP
DNS
Net logon
Network connection
Network location
TCP/IP Net BIOS Helper
Check to make sure that the "Startup Type" is set to "Automatic".

There is also a [quickfix application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357) on the Microsoft website

Comment: No joy with the system restore.  I tried the ipconfig/all command and it says "An internal error occurred: The request is not supported. Please contact Microsoft Product Support for further help. Additional information: Unable to query host name."

Comment: @Alan, there is a fix here but, it doesn't look like an easy read. http://www.technofyed.com/showthread.php?tid=424. I suggest you try this, but if you get stuck or lost, then please ask questions here. If you want, we can go into a chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8809/internetissues

Comment: Just going through the Services on the list you mentioned above.  in DHCP the system status says "stopped" but if I click the start button in the window it brings up a error message "could not start the DHCP client service on local computer.  Error 1068: the dependency service or group failed to start."

Comment: same for DNS...

Comment: rebooted Dave....thank you for your continued help.

Comment: don't think I can login Dave, says something about needing 20 rep..

Comment: still no luck Dave, thanks very much for all of your help anyway, much appreciated.

Comment: Yes seemed to run fine, no error messages at all.  Finished and said needed to restart the machine, machine rebooted then I tried to go online but still same issue.

Comment: @Alan Does the issue happen when you're wired and wireless (if either is an option)